# Testing SSRS Reporting Services reports using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, reporting-services, selenium-webdriver

I am currently testing SSRS reporting services reports in Internet Explorer using Selenium Webdriver.

I can get the reports to load and change the dropdowns/parameters but I don't know how to check if the page has loaded or not. Ideally, by locating elements on the page.

I've tried finding the elements using Id and XPath but no luck so far. I just get the NoSuchElementException error.

Here is an example of what I'm looking to Assert is present on the page.

```
<TD class=A5e6df1155bcd42d5a8e2877b95dc04686l style="HEIGHT: 10mm; WIDTH: 136.98mm; MIN-WIDTH: 136.98mm" abp="570">Top N Destinations by Price</TD>
```

Any help or guidance on testing SSRS with Selenium would be very helpful as I'm not finding much information.

Comment: If the reports it generates is just HTML then this is absolutely no different to how you would use Selenium with a "normal" page. Selenium won't care *where* the HTML comes from. What locators have you tried for what elements? (Show us, in code).

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I think my problem is that the elements I'm trying to locate and nested in tables and divs and I haven't figure out how to do that yet. If I try simple find element by id/Xpath/ClassName, I get NoSuchElementException. Also, I think I read somewhere recently that SSRS generates a new identifier every time. All I really want to do is confirm that the report loaded correctly and data was returned.

Answer (score 2):

In SSRS report id is generating dynamically. So you cannot check with id's. And as of my experience I tried to  check the report(To check the data is given is got correctly printed or not). But I faced the problem because of the dynamically driven id's.Which is not helping to automate test on SSRS report.

Comment: I've come very close to getting this to work, but it doesn't work consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use absolute XPath.

Most element in SSRS report are using dynamic class/id so we cannot use common way to identify element for it. The easiest way I know so far is using chrome with 'Chropath' extension. With this extension you can get the absolute XPath for any element for SSRS report. 
Then use the absolut xPath you get with that extension and then use FindElement to get element. For example:

```
IWebElement fullName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/div[3]/span[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[4]/td[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[3]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[3]/div[1]"));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: re: @SheldonZh
I think I did something like this, but it depends on the version of SSRS server you're looking at. the HTML in the report is slightly different from SSRS 2008/2008R2 server compared to SSRS 2016 for sure.

Comment: ChroPath is no longer available in the Chrome Store but I found Ruto to be very popular.